# IndexError: list index out of range, while extract table

Tags: python, postgresql, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am extracting data from multiple URL's and putting it into a PostgreSQL database. I am struggling when executing the following code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

here is my complete source code:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
import psycopg2
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='--',user='--', password='--', port=--)
cursor = conn.cursor()


for i in range(493):
    my_url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID={}'.format(i)
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page1_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    # html parsing
    soup = soup(page1_html, 'html.parser')


    tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
    for row in tbody:
        cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        if cols:
            vehicle_type = str(cols[0])
            one_time = str(cols[1])
            return_type = str(cols[2])
            monthly_pass = str(cols[3])
            local_vehicle = str(cols[4])

            query = "INSERT INTO toll (vehicle_type, one_time, return_type, monthly_pass, local_vehicle) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
            data = (vehicle_type, one_time, return_type, monthly_pass, local_vehicle)
            cursor.execute(query, data)

# Commit the transaction
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: you should begin by choosing another word for your variable `soup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like some of the pages are missing your key information, you can use [error-catching](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for it, like this:

```
try: 
    tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
except:
    continue  # Skip this page if no items were scrapped
```

It will skip this URL if **any** error occurs, make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: now, its coming
`tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable`

Comment: Updated the comment, it will catch all the errors, use it as long as you're sure, your code works correctly in most of the cases.

Comment: thank u so mch !! its printing the data but throwing an erroe also.

`line 33, in <module>
    local_vehicle = str(cols[4])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That means that some of the `cols` has different format, and contains less than 4 items, change `if cols:` to `if len(cols) > 4:`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer from @pythonist since I don't have the reputation to comment; the table in concern , `tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]` will not have data in all pages which is why your code fails with `IndexError: list index out of range`.

For. eg: 
The page http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=200 has the table, but http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=2 and many likewise might be missing the same.

You could simply catch the error since as mentioned in the answer as it doesn't make any sense to parse the data which isn't' really there.

----- edit ----

Sharing code:

```
page = soup(page1_html, 'html.parser')
try:

    tbody = page('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
    for row in tbody:
        cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        if cols:
            vehicle_type = str(cols[0])
            one_time = str(cols[1])
            return_type = str(cols[2])
            monthly_pass = str(cols[3])
            local_vehicle = str(cols[4])
except IndexError:
    continue
```

Add rest of the code as it is

Comment: make the following changes
1. change variable name of `soup` to say, `page = soup(page1_html, 'html.parser')`

2. Put all your codes with the variable corrected accordingly, inside try, and except the error out.

Comment: Wrapping whole code in try-except clause doesn't make sense, it drastically decreases readability, and after coming back to the code, let's say 3 months later, you'll have no idea which of the lines was throwing an error and why...

Comment: @ Srenadh , It's not fetching any data